# Moving Registers in Assembly (Using Move command)

Tags: assembly

I'm currently learning assembly language in my class, and am still trying to understand the basics of it.
I'm given this question:

```
D5  contains  $FFFFFFFF  just  before  the  instruction  MOVE.W  #$F3,D5 
executes. What is the value in D5 after this instruction?
```

I'm not sure how to approach this, I'm aware that the move command, moves copies "F3" the source int D5, but how would I find the actual result? Where does the F3 go in D5?

Comment: Which processor architecture is this? [Motorola 68k](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/68000_Assembly)?

Comment: Yep, the Motorolla MC68000

Comment: I have not consulted a proper reference yet, but at a guess the answer might be $FFFF00F3

Comment: Any chance you can explain how you did it, I'm still confused on the whole (Word,Byte) difference, my professor has yet to teach it.

Comment: You have *bytes* (8-bits), *words* (16-bits), *double-words* (32-bit) and *quad-word* (64-bit) and *twords* (128-bit). I don't know your Motorola syntax, but I suspect `MOVE.W` is *move-word*, which would move 16-bits with value `$F3` to `D5`. if `D5` was originally `$FFFFFFFF`, then replace the lower 16-bits with `$F3` (`0x00F3`) resulting in `$FFFF00F3`. The low-word (lower 16-bits) are the only bits changed from `0xFFFF` to `0x00F3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In M68K, you have 8x32 bit data registers numbered D0 to D7. 
These are the longword values referenced in MOVE.L src, Dn so, in hex, 0xFFFFFFFF for all 32 bits.
The bottom 16 bits of each data register are the data registers for word operations so, in hex, 0x0000FFFF.
The bottom 8 bits are the byte fields of that data register, so 0x000000FF.
For instance, move.b #$00, D0 sets the lower 8 bits of D0 to zero
EXT.w D0, extends the byte bits in D0 from a byte to a word.
EXT.l D0 extends the word bits in D0 from a word to a longword.

In the example you gave, the upper 16 bits are set to 0x$FFFF and the lower 16 bits are overwritten.